# Which loads YouTube videos faster, the A15 or the M1, and why?

Tags: cpu

Which loads YouTube videos faster, the iPhone A15 chip, the iPad Mini A15, or the iPad Pro M1, and why?

Comment: Why do you want to know? (this question is difficult to answer, and it looks like you're probably really wanting to answer some other, related question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very specific, so it's hard to really say much here.

In general, loading in a YouTube is a very small task for either of those CPUs. The bottleneck usually lies within the network, not the CPU. So the actual speed of loading in the YouTube video depends on your WiFi speed, cellular signal strength, or whatever method of transport, you're using.

If you look only at the CPUs themselves, I would say that this is a tie. They will probably all load the video for you at the same speed in any practical sense.

Comment: That's a fantastic answer; thanks.